# alternative to encased capturing groups in python

Tags: python, regex

At the moment I have a string and I want to extract the contents of the parenthesis. 
This is the string:

```
>>>string = "djdjfksjlfsdk (600m 36.57) fhksjhfhsdhfkjhks"
```

This is the regular expression I am using and it yields the following:

```
>>>regex_output = re.findall(r'\((\d{3,4})m|([\d.:]+\d)\)',string)
>>>regex_output
[('600', ''), ('', '36.57')]
```

As I understand, the empty strings are caused by nesting capturing groups in my regex.
All I want is a list of two variables as:

```
['600','36.57']
```

I could make my new list from my current output but that would defeat the purpose of using the regular expression. So is there a way of achieving my desired output by modifying my regex. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below code also which uses positive look-behind to match the number which was just after to `(` and also  it uses lookahead to match the decimal number which was just before to `)`,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "djdjfksjlfsdk (600m 36.57) fhksjhfhsdhfkjhks"
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=\()\d+|\d+[.:]\d+(?=\))', s, re.M)
>>> m
['600', '36.57']
```

Comment: Hey Avinash, thanks for that answer. Can you please help me with another one? http://regex101.com/r/nF3dD1/2

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "djdjfksjlfsdk (600m 36.57) fhksjhfhsdhfkjhks"
```

You can search for the enclosing `(` and `)`

```
>>> re.search('\((.*?)\)',s).group(1)
'600m 36.57'
```

Then split on the `'m '` characters

```
>>> re.search('\((.*?)\)',s).group(1).split('m ')
['600', '36.57']
```